# Leibniz's Best of All Possible Worlds and the Divine Right of Monarchies

Tags: metaphysics, political-philosophy, theodicy

In my Modern European Philosophy class, we briefly talked about Leibniz's theodicy and his idea that the actual world is the best world that God could have created and the PSR as it pertains to God. I wondered if this could have been used in the 18th century to legitimize the rule of monarchies.

The Divine Rule of Kings assumes that God has given monarchies the right to rule. God's PSR says that His reasoning for action is maximizing perfection. If God gave this right to rulers in this world, it must have been something that maximized perfection in the best possible world. Thus if one were to challenge the authority of a king, they are challenging God's assessment of perfection.

The first country that came to mind was France. I know that atheism was not common in there during the 18th century, so people would not think to question God's ability. This could be used to keep the people of France in line.

Comment: You want to justify the Divine Rule of Kings, yet your justification starts with "if God gave this right", so it is circular. We cannot start from *assuming* that God gave this right to justify it. And if we do not assume it then, perhaps, God did not give this right. The rule of kings is there for people to challenge and overthrow it, and  *that* is what will "maximize perfection".

Comment: The idea of God's origin of monarchs right to rule was  common already in the Middle Age, well before Leibniz.

Comment: @Conifold I don't think my claim was properly conveyed in my original post. Can you tell me if this comment clarifies my idea and if my original post supports my claim?

If there is a Divine Rule of Kings, then Leibniz's Best of All Possible Worlds makes it so that the ruler canot be questioned without questioning God's judgment. If we assume that the average person wouldn't want to challenge God's judgment, then Leibniz's idea would be used to keeping people from wanted to overthrow their ruler.

Comment: This is better. But if we *assume* that the right of kings is God-given then we do not need Leibniz's best possible world to infer that questioning the ruler is blasphemy. It follows directly from our assumption about God's will, which is thereby getting questioned. As Mauro said, this kind of argument in defense of monarchy has been used long before Leibniz, and Leibniz is a superfluous idle wheel in it. What would keep people from wanting to overthrow the ruler is their belief that God endorsed his rule, whether this world is best possible or not is moot.

Comment: @Conifold Ahh, now I see your point. If I assume that it is God who gives these rulers their authority, then it immediately follows that people wouldn't question the ruler since it is God's will. I just feel that if Leibniz's claim was commonly accepted at the time, then it would have led to large societal consequences. This was just the first possible consequence that came to mind, but I see how this already preceeded Leibniz.